# How to check if a url exists with PHP and make it time out after a number of seconds

Tags: php, url, timeout

I've used 2 different methods of checking the url so far:

```
$h = @get_headers($url);
$status = array();
preg_match('/HTTP\/.* ([0-9]+) .*/', $h[0] , $status);
return ($status[1] == 200);
```

and

```
$file_headers = @get_headers($url);
if($file_headers[0] == 'HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found') {
$exists = false;
}
else {
    $exists = true;
}
return $exists;
```

I'm just not sure how I can make these requests time out after a specified number of seconds. My script hangs for minutes, when a url doesn't exist, before it finally comes back as offline status. Any ideas?

SOLUTION:

Used Curl to set the timeout using the following code:

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$data = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
preg_match("/HTTP\/1\.[1|0]\s(\d{3})/",$data,$matches);
return ($matches[1] == 200);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have to roll your own `fsockopen()` with URL handlers enabled, which lets you specify a timeout. But then you're stuck building your own HTTP request from the ground up, so a better solution is to use [curl](http://php.net/curl). You can easily construct a head request in there, and specify a timeout with CURLOPT_CONNECTIMEOUT (for connecting) and CURLOPT_TIMEOUT (general overall timeout).

Comment: Thanks a lot. Using Curl I got this to work. Will post new code in and edit to my original question.

Comment: Keep in mind that cURL may not be installed, it's an optional extension to PHP.  Stream contexts are part of core PHP.

Comment: Yea that's true Mark, good point. I had to double check that cURL was installed before I used this solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use stream contexts for this.  See: https://www.php.net/manual/en/context.http.php.

You can create a context with a short timeout and a method of `HEAD`, and use file_get_contents() to fetch it.

A quick example:

```
$context = stream_context_create(array('http' => array(
    'method' => 'HEAD',
    'timeout' => 10
)));

$response = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
$exists = ($response !== false);
```

This requires HTTP wrappers to be enabled; see: http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.http.php.  If you want to get at the headers of the response, you must access the special global `$http_response_header`.

Comment: Genuine Question: Can you use `HEAD` with `file_get_contents()`? Won't it just result in an empty result?

Comment: @DaveRandom, if you specify `'method' => 'HEAD'` as an option, it will just do a HEAD request.  The response will be an empty string for an existing URL, or `false` for a bogus URL.  Thus, you need to use `if ($response === false)` to test whether that the URL is missing.

Comment: Ahhh gotcha. Didn't have my head properly on the job. +1.

Answer (score 0):

try the [`stream_set_timeout`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-set-timeout.php) function: